# [docusign]The page opened, but the signature could not be completed

Tags: java, docusignapi

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem? The page opened, but the signature could not be completed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv45W.png)

Comment: might want to give more details, the code you wrote, how you did this? 
this can happen if you are not the next signer to open this envelope for example.

Comment: Hi Inbar,Here are some details, code, etc. 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875909/docusignembedded-signature-cannot-display-the-signature-page-normally

Comment: Hi Inbar,It can be used normally. I have to request URL error. The correct one should be: "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient " I used sender. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the recipientId and ensure the email and name match exactly to how they are set in the envelope.
This happens when DocuSign cannot determine the recipient and gives you a read-only sender view of the envelopes.
You also have to specify a clientUserId if you plan to embed this in your app.